# Real World Haskell's CSV Parser implementation

Tags: parsing, csv, haskell

Goerzen et al [present](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) a simple implementation of a CSV file parser to teach readers of *Real World Haskell* about the Parsec parsing combinator library.

Here's a version of their concise program:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ',')
cell = many (noneOf ",\n")
eol = char '\n'

parseCSV :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
parseCSV input = parse csvFile "(unknown)" input
```

The code runs as expected, but **I don't understand the purpose of passing the string "(unknown)" argument in the final line**. Is this some idiom I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's the [`SourceName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#t:SourceName) - it's used to give you some better representation in the error case.

It's part of the `SourcePos` you will get with many things in *Parsec* - for example the [`ParseError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#t:ParseError) you get in the error-case.

You might want to have something like "error in file SourceName on line x / column y" ;)

From inside your own computations you can get it with [`getPosition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:getPosition) (which gives you a `SourcePos` again - from there you can use `sourceName` on to get this parameter)